# django slugify - customize for german umlauts

Tags: python, django

I am a bit stuck in this issue:

as we all know, django has a `slugify` template tag which makes `traume-von-bucher`out of `Träume von Bücher`.

But syntactically, `Träume` should become `Traeume` which would be right german word.

How do I write my own custom tag so that `Ä` will be slugified to `Ae` ?

Comment: i think, i have found it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: `slugify` is actualy a filter not tag. So look for appropriate section

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter
from django.utils.text import slugify

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
@stringfilter
def germanslugify(value):
    replacements = [(u'ä', u'ae')]
    for (s, r) in replacements:
            value = value.replace(s, r)
    return slugify(value)
```

Comment: what if I need to replace multiple umlauts? can I do 
``[(u'ä', u'ae'),(u'ö', u'oe'),(u'ü', u'ue')]`` and loop over them?

Comment: Yep, that's why there's a list there :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the answer by beerbajay.

I wanted to change the default slugify for the whole application
(the default implementation strips out the Norwegian characters 'ø' and 'æ')
without having to fork/subclass everything just to modify the slugify call.

So I decided to monkeypatch it in. It should be safe to do so as long as the custom slugify is implemented like beerbajay
example just doing some simple replacements and calling the original slugify; 
so that its output doesn't break any assumptions about it.

Here's how I did that (tested in Django 1.7 but it probably works in older versions too)

I created an app to contain the monkeypatching code, called `monkeys` in this example.
Add it first in the installed apps so that it will run before all the other apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'monkeys', # The monkey patches app
    #... all the other apps below here
```

In the `monkeys/__init__.py` file add this code:

```
import django.template.defaultfilters
from where.you.defined.it import custom_slugify
#print "MONKEY PATCHING NOW!" 
#Uncomment the above to verify that this code actually called
django.template.defaultfilters.slugify = custom_slugify
```

As long all apps use the django.template.defaultfilters.slugify to make slugs this should work.

Comment: You can also use unicode-slugify, so you don't have to write your own.
https://github.com/mozilla/unicode-slugify